# message queue send and receive

Tags: ipc, vxworks

I am having following program in vxworks which is part of big program

```
 /* defines */
#define MAX_MESSAGES 100
#define MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH 50


if ((msgQStudyId = msgQCreate(MAX_MESSAGES,MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH,MSG_Q_FIFO)) == NULL) {
        printf("msgQCreate in failed\n");
}


CVenkyMsgQWrite *pMsgWrite = new CVenkyMsgQWrite();
    pMsgWrite->OpenWrite();


    CVenkyMsgQRead *pMsgRead = new CVenkyMsgQRead();
    pMsgRead->OpenRead();

class CVenkyMsgQWrite {

public :
    // Constructors and destructors:
    CVenkyMsgQWrite();
    ~CVenkyMsgQWrite();

    RESULT OpenWrite(void);
    void TaskLoop(void);

};


class CVenkyMsgQRead {

public :
    // Constructors and destructors:
    CVenkyMsgQRead();
    ~CVenkyMsgQRead();

    RESULT OpenRead(void);
    void TaskLoop(void);



CVenkyMsgQWrite::CVenkyMsgQWrite() {
    // Open(void);
}

CVenkyMsgQWrite::~CVenkyMsgQWrite() { }

static int WriteTask(const void *envPtr)
{    
    CVenkyMsgQWrite *ctrl = (CVenkyMsgQWrite *)envPtr;
    try
    {
        ctrl->TaskLoop();   // Normal run
        return CI857_ERROR;
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        CI857DBG(printError,("Error in Controller input task\n",0,0,0,0,0,0));      
    }
    return CI857_ERROR;
}

RESULT CVenkyMsgQWrite::OpenWrite(void) {

    RESULT ret = CI857_OK;

    taskSpawn( "VenkyMsgQWrite", 
        78, 
        0,
        4096,  /* stack size */
        WriteTask, 
        this, 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
    return ret;
}

void CVenkyMsgQWrite::TaskLoop(void)
{
    STATUS MsgQStatus = OK;

    // MsgQStatus = msgQSend(msgQStudyId, (char*)pPHData, iDataLength, NO_WAIT, MSG_PRI_NORMAL );
    // if(ERROR == MsgQStatus)
    // {
        // m_pILogHandler->Log((cConfigMod|cError),"#%d: Error: SendToConfMsgQ() msgQSend failed with Err %d.",__LINE__,errnoGet());
    // }

    while(1) {

        char message[] = "message";

        /* send message */
        if((msgQSend(msgQStudyId,message,strlen(message), WAIT_FOREVER,     MSG_PRI_NORMAL)) == ERROR) {
            printf("msgQSend in CVenkyMsgQWrite::TaskLoop failed\n");
        }
        else {
            printf("msgQSend in CVenkyMsgQWrite::TaskLoop success\n");
        }
         vosSleepMs( 1000 );
    }



}

CVenkyMsgQRead::CVenkyMsgQRead() {
    // Open(void);
}

CVenkyMsgQRead::~CVenkyMsgQRead() { }

static int ReadTask(const void *envPtr)
{    
    CVenkyMsgQRead *ctrl = (CVenkyMsgQRead *)envPtr;
    try
    {
        ctrl->TaskLoop();   // Normal run
        return CI857_ERROR;
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        CI857DBG(printError,("Error in Controller input task\n",0,0,0,0,0,0));      
    }
    return CI857_ERROR;
}

RESULT CVenkyMsgQRead::OpenRead(void) {

    RESULT ret = CI857_OK;

    taskSpawn( "VenkyMsgQRead", 
        79, 
        0,
        4096,  /* stack size */
        ReadTask, 
        this, 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
    return ret;
}

void CVenkyMsgQRead::TaskLoop(void)
{
    STATUS MsgQStatus = OK;

    char msgBuf[MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH];
    memset(msgBuf, 0x00, sizeof(msgBuf));

    while(1) {

        /* receive message */
        int msgLength = msgQReceive(msgQStudyId, msgBuf, MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH,  WAIT_FOREVER) ;
        if(msgLength == ERROR) {
            printf("msgQReceive in taskTwo failed\n");  
        }
        else {
            printf(" Length received %d  and string is %s\n", msgLength, msgBuf); 
        }
         vosSleepMs( 5000 );

        memset(msgBuf, 0x00, sizeof(msgBuf));
    }
}
```

Following is the output.

`enter code here`> msgQSend in CVenkyMsgQWrite::TaskLoop success msgQSend in

> CVenkyMsgQWrite::TaskLoop success msgQSend in
>   CVenkyMsgQWrite::TaskLoop success msgQSend in
>   CVenkyMsgQWrite::TaskLoop success msgQSend in
>   CVenkyMsgQWrite::TaskLoop success  Length received 7  and string is
>   message msgQSend in CVenkyMsgQWrite::TaskLoop success msgQSend in
>   CVenkyMsgQWrite::TaskLoop success msgQSend in
>   CVenkyMsgQWrite::TaskLoop success msgQSend in
>   CVenkyMsgQWrite::TaskLoop success msgQSend in
>   CVenkyMsgQWrite::TaskLoop success  Length received 7  and string is
>   message msgQSend in CVenkyMsgQWrite::TaskLoop success msgQSend in
>   CVenkyMsgQWrite::TaskLoop success msgQSend in
>   CVenkyMsgQWrite::TaskLoop success msgQSend in
>   CVenkyMsgQWrite::TaskLoop success msgQSend in
>   CVenkyMsgQWrite::TaskLoop success  Length received 7  and string is
>   message msgQSend in CVenkyMsgQWrite::TaskLoop success msgQSend in
>   CVenkyMsgQWrite::TaskLoop success msgQSend in
>   CVenkyMsgQWrite::TaskLoop success

My question is

1. As we are sending data fast then task is reading as we can have maximum of 100 messages of length 50  I am expecting 5 messages in the queue and lenght received to be 35. But that is not the case as we can see from above output we are reading length of 7 and of single message.

Am I doing right? Is this expected behaviour? If I want to read length of 35 how should I read?

Answer (score 1):

The Message Queue interface is message based, it is not a streaming interface like a TCP socket.

You are invoking msgQSend with a 7 byte message.  Every invocation is a separate message.

Thus, every msgQReceive will receive these message individually.

If you want to receive all the messages from the Queue, then remove your 5 second sleep statement...  msgQReceive will pend the task until a new message comes in.